# ¿ Como usar Variables Amigables?

Tags: php, .htaccess

Como limpiar la url cuando se pasa valores por url y que htaccess las reconozca como variables y esta ayude a ejecutar los contenido.

```html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]


**Asi Debe quedar la URL** 
   #http://localhost/geolocalizacionCibers/Home/Login/gamez


 **gamez es la variable contacto**
    $_GET['contacto'] = 'gamez';


**Aqui se busca limbiar la variable con htaccess **

    RewriteRule ^/geolocalizacionCibers/Home/Login/([a-zA-z]+)$ /geolocalizacionCibers/Home/Login/?contacto=$1



   


**Este sera el links quien activara el GET**
<nav>
 <ul>
  <li>
   <!-- <a href="/geolocalizacionCibers/Home/Login/Anio2019">Login</a> -->
   <a href="/geolocalizacionCibers/Home/Login/gamez">Contacto</a>
  </li>
 </ul>
</nav>


<?php 
    if(isset($_GET['contacto'] ) ){
         echo $_GET['contacto'];        
 }
 ?>

**El ECHO deberia imprimir el contacto que fue enviado por el href llamado gamez pero no pasa nada en el procedimiento**
```

**Yo uso MVC ahi esta la imagen para mayor claridad**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: hace un var dump a GET y fijate que te devuelve primero y despues vas jugando con las configuraciones de apache var_dump($_GET);

Comment: Me retorna NULL el $_GET['contacto'];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes utilizar la siguiente modificación que realice en tu código exactamente en RewriteRule nesesitavas corregir unos pequeños errores.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]

**Asi Debe quedar la URL** 
   #http://localhost/geolocalizacionCibers/Home/Login/gamez


 **gamez es la variable contacto**
    $_GET['contacto'] = 'gamez';


#Aqui se busca limbiar la variable con htaccess


##actualizacion
RewriteRule ^geolocalizacionCibers/Home/Login/(.+)/?$ geolocalizacionCibers/Home/Login/?contacto=$1.php?id=$1




**Este sera el links quien activara el GET**
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <!-- <a href="/geolocalizacionCibers/Home/Login/Anio2019">Login</a> -->
            <a href="/geolocalizacionCibers/Home/Login/gamez">Contacto</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>


<?php 
    if(isset($_GET['contacto'] ) ){
         echo $_GET['contacto'];        
 }

 var_dump($_GET);
 ?>

**El ECHO deberia imprimir el contacto que fue enviado por el href llamado gamez pero no pasa nada en el procedimiento**
```

Comment: Me sigue dando Null

Comment: ^geolocalizacionCibers/Home/Login/(.+) Tiene que estar igual al href con su / pero nada aun. si le quito el / al href lo que hace es insertar el href varias veces en la url

Comment: que raro revisare tal cual como tienes tu configuracion de apache.

Comment: Oye!! El contacto solo es un variable y no es un archivo sera es el error ?. Porque yo solo busco insertar una variable en la misma pagina. Y eso esta demas en mi caso .php?id=$1 .. Ya que deseo imprimir en la misma pagina y no redireccionar

Comment: a no es me paso de quitarla era un RewriteRule que tenia anteriormente hecho

Comment: No busco redireccionar solo quiero ejecutarlo en la misma pagina, Para ese caso cual seria la modificacion del RewriteRule

Comment: create un archivo demo.php y en el httacsess limpialo y pone <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_env.c>
SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE On
</IfModule>
RewriteEngine on
 RewriteRule ^geolocalizacionCibers/Home/Login/(.+)$ demo.php?contacto=$1

Comment: ami me funcion bien

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87778/discussion-between-matias-and-gamez).